# Mixsing @Transactional & @Controller Semantics on a REST Api

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I'd like to expose the backend as 'Resources' (like Restlet) and eliminate the Service Layer so a Rest Resource can direclty interact with a Dao. This way the Resource *is* the contract and not the Interface.

Is there a problem using @Transactional semantics on a Spring MVC 3 Controller if the transactions are managed locally by Spring? Any gotchas with Rollback and catching exceptions?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@Transactional
public void updateUser(@PathVariable Long userId, @RequestBody ProfileUser user) {

   // dao update
}

spring config:
<tx:annotation-driven />
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  think you could run into issues here. By default Spring will use a JDK dynamic proxy to apply the transactional behaviour to your method. This relies on your controller implementing a suitable interface i.e. one which exposes an updateUser method. There is an excellent blog post on the Spring [blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/23/understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring/).

It is likely that you'll see an error due to Spring failing to find the method on the proxy.

You can use your above approach if you tell Spring to use CGLIB based proxies. This is described in the documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-autoproxy-force-CGLIB).